# Groovy - Problem with character in the password

Tags: jenkins, groovy

This is bugging me for a while. In Jenkins I have the correct password.
Password looks something like this:

```
def myPass = 'ZagZS5DMK6$xq26Nx'
```

Please note the "$" character. Now I want to export that password in to the variable:

```
--set env.MYSQL_PASSWORD=${mySqlPassword} \
```

The password looks like this:

```
ZagZS5DMK6
```

I was playing around, and I tried using `URLencoder`, like this:

```
--set env.MYSQL_PASSWORD=${URLEncoder.encode(mySqlPassword)} \
```

And the password is broken still.

What can I do to preserve my password with the special characters?

Comment: At the risk of sounding obvious.. did you try escaping the `$`? ie: `def myPass = 'ZagZS5DMK6\$xq26Nx'` or `def myPass = 'ZagZS5DMK6\\$xq26Nx'`? or perhaps you can use the unicode character `\u0024`

Comment: The password is dynamic. It comes from terraform, and I have no control over it. It has to go in ENV exactly as is

Comment: Spitballing: have you tried quoting the variable? `--set env.MYSQL_PASSWORD='${mySqlPassword}'`

Comment: That did the trick. Can you please make an answer so I accept it? :)

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. there you go :) glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is being interpreted as `ZagZS5DMK6` followed by a variable called `$xq26Nx`, which doesn't exist so it expands to an empty string.

Putting single quotes around the string will avoid the `$` being interpreted as the beginning of a variable name and will be interpreted literally, instead.

```
--set env.MYSQL_PASSWORD='${mySqlPassword}'
```